# Remove multiple Activities to go Back to Dashboard from Options menu

Tags: android

I have a Optionsmenu in my Android App, in which is a Button to Go Back to the Apps Dashboad and remove all Activities laying upon that, also removing the History. How is this possible?

thx

Got the Answer:

That's what does the Trick:

myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.dashboard:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DashBoard.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what does the Trick:

myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);